# PowerShell script working on Linux (Ubuntu pwsh) but not on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell

The following powershell script is arranging the files by their extension in appropriate directory.
What I did is first find all the unique extensions in the target folder and called copy for all those extensions but it doesn't work on Windows .I have used correct path for Windows.

Currently folders are being created but the file is not being copied from source folder to destination folder.

```
$source = "/home/shubham/ps/" #location of starting directory
$destination = "/home/shubham/ps/check"; #location where files will be   `copied to`
$extensionArray = @(Get-ChildItem ($source) |
                  Select-Object Extension |
                  Sort-Object Extension |
                  Get-Unique -AsString)
echo ($extensionArray[3])
[string[]]$l_array = ($extensionArray | Out-String -Stream) -notmatch '^$' |
                     select -Skip 2

for ($i=0; $i -lt $extensionArray.Length; $i++) {
    $x = $l_array[$i]

    $ext = "*" + "$x"

    #foreach ($x in $extension_array){
    echo ("*" + ($x))
    $newsrc = ($source) + "/" + ($ext)
    $files = @("", "*" + ($x)) #edit .xlsx to your desired extension
    $outputPath = ($destination) + "_" + ($x)

    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path ($outputpath);
    Copy-Item -Path $newsrc -Filter ($ext) -Destination $outputPath -Container 
}
echo "end"
```

Comment: What defines doesn't work? Are you getting error messages or is something else happening?

Comment: Edit provided currently the files are not being copied from one folder to another on windows but it works fine on ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried using the `-Force` and `-Debug` parameters with `Move-Item` when on Windows to see what's happening? Also, have you tried stepping through your code in the PS ISE on Windows to view variables values?

Comment: Please stop that weird "putting parentheses around variables" thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-3.0) (emphasis mine):

> **-Path**
>   Specifies, as a string array, the path to the items to copy.
>   Type: String[]
>   Position: 1
>   Default value:    None
>   Accept pipeline input:    True (ByPropertyName, ByValue)
>   *Accept wildcard characters:  False*

Meaning paths like `/home/shubham/ps/*.docx` are not supported by `Copy-Item`. It probably works on Linux because the shell already expands the wildcard to a list of absolute paths before `Copy-Item` sees it.

Not to mention that your code is overly complicated. Something like this should suffice:

```
$src = '/home/shubham/ps/'
$dst = '/home/shubham/ps/check'

$files = Get-ChildItem $src

$files |
    Select-Object -Expand Extension -Unique |
    New-Item -Path $dst -Name {'_' + $_.TrimStart('.')} -Type Directory |
    Out-Null

$files | Copy-Item -Destination {Join-Path $dst ('_' + $_.Extension.TrimStart('.')} -Container
```